# Why asyncio.StreamReader.read return didn't block the thread?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I tried to run this asyncio example https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-stream.html?highlight=start_server#tcp-echo-server-using-streams

This line makes me confused:

```
data = yield from reader.read(100) # data -> b'Hello World!'
```

The client sends string `'Hello World!'` to the server, the `Bytearray` length is less than 100.

> coroutine read(n=-1) Read up to n bytes. If n is not provided, or set
>   to -1, read until EOF and return all read bytes.
>
> If the EOF was received and the internal buffer is empty, return an
>   empty bytes object.
>
> This method is a coroutine.

I didn't send `EOF` in client side, So why the `read` function didn't blocked? 
Does it mean the `Bytearray` contains `EOF` after `string.encode`?

Comment: Did you check the difference between `return` and `yield`?

Comment: Sorry, the word `return` which I mean the return value of `read` function execution (the value came from yield inside the read function).

Comment: I do not quite understand your answer here, if you could, please reformulate it. In any case, my comment is to suggest that there is a difference between `yield` and `return`, and this might be the origin of your confusion. Plus,, if the Bytearray is less than 100, why would you be expecting it to return more than that? Would that not be your EOF?

Comment: @MikeMajara I expect the server won't receive anything, because the Bytearray suppose don't contain `EOF` and the length is less than 100. the server's session shall be blocked until it receives specified length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't send EOF in client side, So why the read function didn't blocked?

Because some data was received, and `read` provided it. The documentation you cited explicitly says that `read(n)` reads "**up to** n bytes". This is a feature: if `read(n)` returned only when the full n bytes are available, it would introduce [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) in the echo server, which wouldn't echo anything until the full amount was read in. With such semantics, the only way to have an echo server without the buffer-induced latency would be to read data byte by byte with `read(1)`, which would be horribly inefficient.

The intended meaning of `read(n)`, which the echo server uses, is "give me the data as soon as it's available, but no more than *n* bytes at a time". A limit must be provided not because it's necessarily meaningful, but simply to prevent a rogue peer from flooding your memory by sending a lot of data.

Note that, with such `read()` specified like that, it is easy to define another function that reads the data until the **exact** amount is available; in fact, such a method on `StreamReader` already exists: [`readexactly`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly).

> Does it mean the Bytearray contains EOF after string.encode?

A [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object (which is distinct from a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects) object) returned by `read` never "contains EOF" because EOF is not a character, it is a condition signaled out-of-band. In the `StreamReader` API, the EOF condition is indicated by `read` returning an empty bytes object.